# Why I am getting shifted output when write to a text after converting it to xls file in java

Tags: java, excel, csv, io, html-parsing

I am writing outputs of parsed web pages into two text files. "CrawledURLS.txt" saves the crawled pages and "CrawledURLSERROR.txt" saves uncrawled we pages. Since i should get some plot of output data, i converted the .txt files to .xls file. I am getting more than "300.000" URLs. When i stop the program to check the outputs i see that some of columns are shifted to right or it contains incorrect information.

Here is where i am writing the output:

```
 LinkNode deque(){

    LinkNode link = pQUEUE.poll();
    link.setDequeTime(new DateTime());
    for (LinkNode l : pQUEUE) {
        DateTime start = new DateTime();
        l.setDequeTime(start);
        l.setStartTime(start);

        PingTaskManager.ping(l);
        if(l.getStatus()!= null && l.getStatus().equals(LinkNodeStatus.OK)) {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("CrawledURLS.txt",true)))){

                l.setEndTime(new DateTime());
                out.println( l.getUrl() + ": "+ l.getWeight() +  " InTime: "+
                Util.formatDate(l.getDequeTime()) + " OutTime: " + Util.formatDate(l.getEnqueTime())+" Waiting duration :" + l.waitingInQueue()
                + "  Processing duration :" + l.linkProcessingDuration() );

             } catch(IOException e){

             }

        }  else {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("CrawledURLSERROR.txt",true)))){


                l.setEndTime(new DateTime());
                out.println( l.getUrl() + ": "+ l.getWeight() +  " InTime : "+
                Util.formatDate(l.getDequeTime()) + " OutTime : " + Util.formatDate(l.getEnqueTime())+" Waiting duration :" + l.waitingInQueue()
                + "  Processing duration :" + l.linkProcessingDuration() );

             } catch(IOException e){

             }
        }    
    }

    return link;
}
```

And this is the output what i am getting:

[image: Output]

I have two questions about this issue:

1- Why this corruption is done ?

2- How do i convert my code to output with .csv file instead of .txt ? Will that solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good bet that writing CSV files will fix this since it appears the problem is Excel guessing how to put your text data into columns.

Note that CSV is not a standard. CSV formats vary between different programs, e.g. how to do quoting and whether newlines can be quoted or not.

So use a debugged CSV library such as the Apache library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ and set it to write data for Excel.

Also, do not (re)open an output file once per output line. That can cause problems and it's sure to be slow. Instead, open the two output files, write a header row to each file (giving the column names), then loop over the data, adding data value rows, and finally close the files.

(If CSV quoting doesn't suffice for your data, you can switch to a well-defined standard like JSON or XML.)